# Plugin not triggered in cordova/phonegap application

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins

The plugin de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background-mode (which can be found on github at: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) is not activating correctly inside of my application. Here is the code I am running in my index.js:

```
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
            // Android customization
            cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.setDefaults({ text:'Doing heavy tasks.'});
            // Enable background mode
            cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();

            // Called when background mode has been activated
            cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.onactivate = function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    alert('activated')
                    // Modify the currently displayed notification
                    cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.configure({
                        text:'Running in background for more than 5s now.'
                    });
                }, 5000);
            }
        }, false);
        cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();
```

However, when I run it, the alert('activated') does not trigger. How can I fix this? I have my code up on github @ https://github.com/acquainting/Cordova-Test.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes.... why is the plugin not triggering?

Comment: You need to update your original message.

Answer (score 0):

@Rob,
it appears you are new to programming, or phonegap, or both. Your statements in your original message are conflicting. The statements conflict with each other. I suggest, in future, you use a linear time-line for explanation.

I do NOT use Phonegap CLI. However, after looking at your source code, you need to add a phonegap verion.

EXAMPLE:

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.5.0" />
```

Best of Luck,
Jesse

Comment: EDIT: It still does not work. Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: Your issue will not be fixed here. Try [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap) or [nitobi](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi)